# Oozie workflow to execute spark job

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I have setup a workflow to execute a spark job. The workflow when ran with normal script seems to be working fine and Spark application is working perfectly when it it is executed separately.

But, when the Oozie workflow is made to execute spark job,I'm getting the following error

```
18/05/09 17:38:40 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.create(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.create(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;
```

I'm using Spark of version 2.1.0 and Scala of 2.11.8 but still I'm facing the issue.

Let me know if I'm missing anything

Comment: _" the Oozie workflow is made to execute spark job"_ > using a Spark action or a Shell action? In the case of a Spark action, did you enable the system shared libs? Is there a Spark install on cluster nodes or not?

Comment: I'm using shell action and not spark action.Spark is installed on the cluster nodes